# How to handle String data in flutter_bluetooth_serial package?

Tags: android, flutter, hc-05

I'm using `flutter_bluetooth_serial` package to communicate with `HC-05` bluetooth module in my Flutter app. The module is responsible to send the String `HC05-1 Mode1 Data: 1.696728 V` to my app in each second, however while receiving the data, the value was separated into several chunks like the following:

```
I/flutter (24772): Data incoming: H
I/flutter (24772): Data incoming: C05-1 Mo
I/flutter (24772): Data incoming: de1 Data:
I/flutter (24772): Data incoming: 1.696728
I/flutter (24772): Data incoming: V
```

Here is the Flutter code to receive data:

```
conn.input.listen((Uint8List data) {
          String dataStr = ascii.decode(data);
          print('Data incoming: $dataStr');
        })
```

Here is the C code I've got to send data:

```
sprintf((char*)sendbuf, "HC05-1 Mode1 Data: %f V\r\n", ttemp)
// send to bluetooth module
u2_printf("HC05-1 Mode1 Data: %f V\r\n", ttemp)
```

I there any way to receive the whole string value instead of the chunk at one time?

Answer (score 1):

```
Create variable  String message='';
```

then make changes in your function

```
conn.input.listen((Uint8List data) {
      String dataStr = ascii.decode(data);
      message+=dataStr;
        if (dataStr.contains('\n')) {
          print(message); // here you get complete string 
          message = '';   //clear buffer to accept new string
        }
    })
```